# xcodebuild: There are no accounts registered with Xcode

Tags: xcodebuild

xcodebuild fails to archive, saying "There are no accounts registered with Xcode". This is true - I'm trying to build on a CI server, so there is no direct access to Xcode to add an account. But I am proving authentication keys to the Apple Developer account, and the development certificate is in the keychain. Automatic signing is on, and DEVELOPMENT_TEAM is set in the pbxproj file.

```
xcrun xcodebuild archive \
    -project MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj \
    -scheme MyApp \
    -configuration Release \
    -sdk iphoneos \
    -destination "generic/platform=iOS" \
    -archivePath MyApp/Build/Applications/MyApp.xcarchive \
    -allowProvisioningUpdates \
    -authenticationKeyID ... \
    -authenticationKeyIssuerID ... \
    DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=Build/Applications
```

I also tried adding `authenticationKeyPath` and `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM explicitly on the command line, but it didn't change anything. Everything works if I add an account to Xcode, but... this is supposed to run on a CI server.

Update: Thinking about this more, the error makes sense: Xcode needs to know who is building so it can determine which certificates they have access to - not all members of the team have the same roles. But with only a team, it can't figure out the user. I thought the authentication key is tied to the user, but that doesn't seem to be the case. So the question is: how to tell xcodebuild which user is building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a provisioning profile issue. The "no accounts" error is usually accompanied by a second "No profiles for " error, like

```
`error: No profiles for '<app ID>' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '<app ID>'. (in target '<target>' from project '<projec>')`
```

It's this second error that's actually the issue, not the absence of a  developer account. It means you have the wrong profile.

**Solution**

Use the provisioning profile from the `Provisioning Profiles` directory, rather than the one downloaded from Apple Developer. I don't what the difference is, but they have different file sizes.

1. Do a local build to generate the profile in the `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` directory
2. Examine the files in that directory to find the one with the correct App ID
3. Upload that file to the GH repo secret:

   ```
    base64 -i ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/<guid>.mobileprovision | pbcopy
   ```